# Keep-Alive across domains

Tags: javascript, session, iframe, cross-domain, keep-alive

My application is being presented inside an iframe of a 3rd party vendor.

The vendor has a session timeout that logs the user out after 10 minutes. When navigating within our iframe app, the vendor session isn't being extended since no activity is happening within their domain.

Right now I am doing a hacky solution where we refresh the entire browser window every time the user goes back to our home page, but that is not a good solution.

We asked the vendor and they provided a URL endpoint to keep the session alive, but when I call that endpoint I am getting a 302 redirect to their login page which also throws a "blocked by CORS policy" response.

Since our applications are across domains, I'm not sure what I should be doing.

Should I be asking them to update their control-origin headers to allow all domains for the keepalive endpoint? But that wouldn't alleviate the 302 redirect right?

Should they be exposing a JavaScript function in the parent window that I can call?

Comment: How does vendor insert your app....using script or just iframe html?

Comment: Last idea would be an easy solution ... could use postMessage api within your app to send message to parent  window and parent could use ajax to keep session alive

Comment: They are POSTing the iframe to our SSO authentication endpoint. I am not familiar with postMessage, so I will have to do some review. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Might also be able to cURL request from your server to theirs using some sort of token that would allow them to identify which session